# How do most daemon applications do their logging in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, logging, syslog, rsyslog

How do most daemons do their logging these days. syslog or is there a newer logging facility that I'm not aware of? or custom?

The reason I ask is that I started using syslog but noticed most of the daemon processes were not logging to the normal files and they are not configured in the syslog config files.

That leads me to believe they are doing their own thing.

Which is preferred? why are modern apps steering clear of syslog?

Comment: Modern apps are steering clear of syslog? Where did you get that?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is rsyslog. Did you set correctly?

Comment: So you just use the normal openlog/syslog/closelog api's and they end up in rsyslog?  that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Syslog is the standard way of logging messages. If you don't see your daemons messages, try to add this line to your syslogd configuration, reload the daemon then look at `/var/log/all.log`:

```
*.* /var/log/all.log
```